JPMC Forage Task 1 Code not working in VSCode but works in PyCharm
For the JPMC Forage SWE task 1, I am running code that has already been written with minor bugs but receive syntax errors. These errors are only in VSCode and the code runs perfectly in PyCharm.
GitHub Repo of Code. There are syntax errors after running both server.py and then client.py like said in the tutorial.
I looked at the environment, and it was installed correctly. I looked up the window error 10061 but was unable to locate the issue.
error code when server.py runs
File "c:\Users\Jemin\OneDrive\Desktop\Again\forage-jpmc-swe-task-1\server3.py", line 340, in <module>
    run(App())
        ^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Jemin\OneDrive\Desktop\Again\forage-jpmc-swe-task-1\server3.py", line 263, in __init__
    self._sim_start, _, _ = next(self._data_1)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
StopIteration
PS C:\Users\Jemin\OneDrive\Desktop\Again>


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's difficult to know what the issue is given your post in its current state.  Please include a minimal reproducible example as well as include the full traceback error.   Where is this error 10061?
